# windows server 2008 R2 date format reverts to US

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2, date-format

Very strange phenomena with Windows 2008 R2 setup and scratching my head for more than couple of hours now. What is happening when an Application is run via a user it picks up correct date format i.e. DD/MM/YYYY and however when run via Task Scheduler, the same applications yields US date format.

I have changed the regional setting, the Locale setting and every possible options/configurations I can think of that may affect date however it still does not work. Can anyone help?

Chao,
Marko.....

Answer (score 1):

Problem can be fixed by setting culture configuration key

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/281496/Windows-SERVER-R-Datetime-Format-Problem